Render destructured objects as escaped JSON in Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter
As part of utilising more structured logging in Serilog, we need to change the output format of the logs to be easily copyable as JSON where possible.
If I setup a basic Worker service application and register Serilog:
builder.Services.AddSerilog(loggerConfig => 
{
    loggerConfig
        .WriteTo.File(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(), "output.json");
});

And then subsequently log data in two different ways:
using System.Text.Json;

namespace LoggingTests;

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var message = new ExampleMessage(
            ExampleText: "Test Message",
            ExampleNumber: 120,
            ExamplePerson: new Person("John", "Smith"),
            OtherPeople: [new Person("Another", "Person"), new Person("YetAnother", "Person")]
        );
        _logger.LogWarning("Example Structured Payload: {@Message}", message);
        _logger.LogWarning("Example Structured Payload: {@Message}", JsonSerializer.Serialize(message));
        _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    record ExampleMessage(string ExampleText, int ExampleNumber, Person ExamplePerson, IEnumerable<Person> OtherPeople);
    record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
}


The latter way of logging the message is not the correct way to log it and we still want the properties destructured and included in the context however I'm wondering for the formatting of the message how I would achieve serialising the object as escaped JSON as is the case with the latter message. To compare the two:
{
    "@t": "2024-04-24T01:28:25.4060384Z",
    "@m": "Example Structured Payload: ExampleMessage { ExampleText: \"Test Message\", ExampleNumber: 120, ExamplePerson: Person { FirstName: \"John\", LastName: \"Smith\" }, OtherPeople: [Person { FirstName: \"Another\", LastName: \"Person\" }, Person { FirstName: \"YetAnother\", LastName: \"Person\" }] }",
    "@i": "1227d6a4",
    "@l": "Warning",
    "Message": {
        "ExampleText": "Test Message",
        "ExampleNumber": 120,
        "ExamplePerson": {
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "$type": "Person"
        },
        "OtherPeople": [
            {
                "FirstName": "Another",
                "LastName": "Person",
                "$type": "Person"
            },
            {
                "FirstName": "YetAnother",
                "LastName": "Person",
                "$type": "Person"
            }
        ],
        "$type": "ExampleMessage"
    },
    "SourceContext": "LoggingTests.Worker"
}

{
    "@t": "2024-04-24T01:28:25.4326606Z",
    "@m": "Example Structured Payload: \"{\\\"ExampleText\\\":\\\"Test Message\\\",\\\"ExampleNumber\\\":120,\\\"ExamplePerson\\\":{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"John\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Smith\\\"},\\\"OtherPeople\\\":[{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Another\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Person\\\"},{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"YetAnother\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Person\\\"}]}\"",
    "@i": "1227d6a4",
    "@l": "Warning",
    "Message": "{\"ExampleText\":\"Test Message\",\"ExampleNumber\":120,\"ExamplePerson\":{\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Smith\"},\"OtherPeople\":[{\"FirstName\":\"Another\",\"LastName\":\"Person\"},{\"FirstName\":\"YetAnother\",\"LastName\":\"Person\"}]}",
    "SourceContext": "LoggingTests.Worker"
}

In an ideal outcome, the log message would look like:
{
    "@t": "2024-04-24T01:28:25.4326606Z",
    "@m": "Example Structured Payload: \"{\\\"ExampleText\\\":\\\"Test Message\\\",\\\"ExampleNumber\\\":120,\\\"ExamplePerson\\\":{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"John\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Smith\\\"},\\\"OtherPeople\\\":[{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Another\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Person\\\"},{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"YetAnother\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Person\\\"}]}\"",
    "@i": "1227d6a4",
    "@l": "Warning",
    "Message": {
        "ExampleText": "Test Message",
        "ExampleNumber": 120,
        "ExamplePerson": {
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "$type": "Person"
        },
        "OtherPeople": [
            {
                "FirstName": "Another",
                "LastName": "Person",
                "$type": "Person"
            },
            {
                "FirstName": "YetAnother",
                "LastName": "Person",
                "$type": "Person"
            }
        ],
        "$type": "ExampleMessage"
    },
    "SourceContext": "LoggingTests.Worker"
}

Any help is appreciated, there's plenty of documentation for logging with the default text formatter to JSON but including escaped JSON in a JSON message is an edge case by the looks of it.
